# Prevent media keys volume control affecting system volume

Tags: windows, keyboard, media-keys

I've just purchased a DasKeyboard 4, and I'd like to have the volume controls only affect my media player (Winamp), but not the system volume.  (Purely for convenience reasons - I want to be able to easily alter/mute my music without also muting all other audio sources)

I found some info in related questions regarding changing the default programs for a given file association (in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\`), but I'm not sure what key names/values I would need to create to make Windows ignore the event altogether.

I also have a suspicion that if I manage to make Windows ignore the appropriate WM_APPCOMMAND events in this way, they'll never be propagated to Winamp anyway.

The events in question are:

- APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN (9)
- APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP (10)

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?